# JpaRepository is creating a wrong query

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following query

```java
package gt.com.anibal.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import gt.com.anibal.model.Order;

@Repository
public interface OrderDao extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{
    
    //@Query("SELECT o FROM Order o")
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Order o WHERE o.price = ?1", nativeQuery = true) //native query
    public List<Order> findOrder(double price);
}
```

And this is the error

```java
    SELECT
        * 
    FROM
        
    Order o WHERE
        o.price = ?
10:13 TRACE 13460 --- [nio-9091-exec-2] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [DOUBLE] - [25.0]
10:13  WARN 13460 --- [nio-9091-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
10:13 ERROR 13460 --- [nio-9091-exec-2] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order o WHERE o.price = 25.0' at line 1
10:13 ERROR 13460 --- [nio-9091-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Order o WHERE o.price = 25.0' at line 1
```

If I run the query on MySQL, it works fine

```
 SELECT
        * 
    FROM

    test.Order o WHERE
        o.price = 25.0
```

but I think the JpaRepository it's creating a space blank between the from and where, when I use JpaRepository in another Entity, the query it's different in my console

```java
package gt.com.anibal.dao;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import gt.com.anibal.model.Persona;

@Repository
public interface PersonaDao extends JpaRepository<Persona, Long> {

}
```

Here is the result, I don't see the space blank between from and the next line, I don't know if that is the problem or it is another problem.

```
    select
        persona0_.id_persona as id_perso1_3_,
        persona0_.apellido as apellido2_3_,
        persona0_.email as email3_3_,
        persona0_.nombre as nombre4_3_,
        persona0_.telefono as telefono5_3_ 
    from
        persona persona0_
```

This is my Entity

```java
package gt.com.anibal.model;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "order" )
public class Order {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "idorder", columnDefinition = "int")
    private Long idOrder;

    @Column( name = "description")
    private String descriptions;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
    private Set<Customer> customer = new HashSet<>();

    @Column( name = "date")
    private Date date;
    
    @Column( name = "price", precision = 10, scale = 2)
    private double price;

    public Long getIdOrder() {
        return idOrder;
    }

    public void setIdOrder(Long idOrder) {
        this.idOrder = idOrder;
    }

    public String getDescriptions() {
        return descriptions;
    }

    public void setDescriptions(String descriptions) {
        this.descriptions = descriptions;
    }

    public Set<Customer> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Set<Customer> customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    
    
    

}
```

and this is my table on MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `order` (
  `idOrder` int NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `idCustomer` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOrder`),
  KEY `fk_order_customer_idx` (`idOrder`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_order_customer` FOREIGN KEY (`idOrder`) REFERENCES `customer` (`idCustomer`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Is your Order table located in a different schema? I can see test.Order in your manual query example but not in other queries or your code.

Comment: I have all entities in the same schema, persona, and order, I was trying some queries to practice

Comment: Order is a reserved keyword at the SQL, you have to escape it both in the query "select * from \`order\`..." (but you don't need the native one) and at the entity @Table(name = "\`order\`")

Comment: thank you for suggestion, that work fine with that, I changed the name of my table on MySQL and my Entity for other name

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use [JPA Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods) for this kind of simple queries.

Your method should be named as follows:

```java
@Repository
public interface OrderDao extends JpaRepository<Order, Long>{
    List<Order> findByPrice(double price);
}
```

This is a more clean code.

If you want to use native queries for further cases, you should replace your "?1" for the name of your method variable name prefixed by a semicolon like this ":price".

Comment: I tried to use in that way, but I have the same problem, SQL Syntax,

Comment: I can see now what is the problem. Maybe your table name is order, not Order, try to match the name of your table, would you mind sharing to us your Entity object and your DDL?, maybe we can troubleshooting much better knowing that.

Comment: I edit my problem, and I added my Entity and my DDL

Answer (score 1):

what @rortegat suggested is a good way to write simple queries[at least to me].
Now, in your query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Order o WHERE o.price = ?1", nativeQuery = true)
```

Here `*` means rows/records of all columns but your method is returning `List<Order>` which is not compatible.
Instead, change your query like this:
`@Query(value = "SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.price = ?1", nativeQuery = true`)

Here, `SELECT o FROM Order o` this part means you are returning Order instance from your query by your alias `o`.

Comment: I tried using this way, if you see, I have commented that line, when I tried

Comment: I don't see any problem then. Can you please check @ 
Andriy Slobodyanyk comment in your question above? Just rename the table and try with that. Should work. Obviously, use `o` instead of `*` sign.

Answer (score 0):

When you use nativeQuery = true, it will interpret as a standard SQL that you can execute directly in MySQL. If you remove nativeQuery = true, @Query will interpret as JPQL. Which one are you trying to use?

Try this:

Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Order WHERE price = ?1", nativeQuery = true) //native query

When nativeQuery is true, Order must be the table name and price must be the column name.

Or else, try this to use jpql:

Query(value = "SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.price = ?1")

Comment: I tried without nativeQuery, and I used  @Query(value = "SELECT o FROM Order o WHERE o.price = ?1"), but I have the same problem